# One signal service worker alongside app service worker

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, onesignal

I am trying to implement One signal within my current Vue app. I already have a service worker for PWA so One signal is conflicting with it. I did found [official explanation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-service-worker-faq#integrating-multiple-service-workers), but I find it somehow conflicting.

Specifically:

> It is recommended to modify both OneSignalSDKWorker.js and OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js to import your other service worker scripts...

So I did:

```
importScripts('/service-worker.js');
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
```

and

```
importScripts('/service-worker.js');
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
```

Reloading the page shows that install event from my service worker is triggering, so I guess that part works fine.

What I'm confused with is this part:

> Additionally, please be sure to modify your site's code to register OneSignalSDKWorker.js instead of your own worker. You can do this with code like: `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');`

Implementation part says to do:

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
    window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({ ... });
    });
</script>
```

But if I place this after:

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
        });
    }
</script>
```

I see that my service worker install event gets triggered twice. So now I am unsure of which part is here duplicate? If without the `register('/OneSignalSDKWorker.js')` part of the code the service worker gets installed, why do I even need that part? Is it already integrated within One signal init or SDK require? Are docs then outdated?